# How to use opencv 2.4.x for tegra (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, tegra

I'm specifically trying to use the method tegra::calcSharrDeriv(src, dst)
from within my c++ code but the compiler can't find the package 'tegra'. Is there a particular header I should include? Btw it's not a matter of namespace, cv::tegra::calcSharrDeriv(src, dst) doesn't work either.
I'm compiling my code on a tx1 that has opencv for tegra.